# How to replace a (connected) device in kaa middle ware with out altering endpoint hash?

Tags: kaa

Right now, Kaa middelware assign a unique end point hash to each endpoint as a unique identification. hence, all the communication to this device and the data stores in the database is based on this endpoint hash (EndpointId) So, if user need to replaced this device due to some reasons. Does the new device have a same endpoint hash? if Yes, then what are the steps to replaced endpoint(node)? if no, then How can user syncs the previously stored data with the new endpoint hash?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Any help from Kaa Team is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Endpoint key hash is actually a hash (result of hash function operation) of the Endpoint public key.

This means that you can replace a device with another one without change of the endpoint key hash (provided it uses the same key pair).